# Tool Bar buttons Intially faded Out

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, overlay, uitoolbar

i have created a overlay view of tool bar on camera controller , i have added 5 buttons as per my requirments on tool bar , 
error is when i run the application toolbar items i.e button are intially faded and are invisible as :[image] , the grey space is the defined toolbar , when i tap on the tool bar , the buttons actions are perfomed but buttons are not visible . Thanks in advance.

```
UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 55)];


    NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:(@"Album") style: UIBarStyleDefault target:self action:@selector(selectAlbum)],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace  target:self action:nil],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil],
                    nil];

    [toolBar setItems: items animated:NO];
```

Above is reference code .

Comment: I dont' quite get your question, but by looking at your code, I can see that you're adding 2 consecutive flexible spaces into your toolbar.

Comment: There are 5 buttons on Ui toolbar one is action button and other are just dummy spaces and this view is overlayed on camera view so initially only toolbar shows when I tap or hover on toolbar button is displayed . Issue is button is not displayed initially when I hover on tool bar then button become visible

Comment: The grey colour space is occupied by tool bar on the top of the view

Comment: If you use Debug View Hierarchy, are the buttons there? Are the frames correct? Do you see any difference if you use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` instead of `UIBarStyleDefault`?

Comment: In debug view tool bar  and button both are available , but the Button Text is not visible in debug view